# Printing a CP850 encoded string with Ruby (IRB)

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding, io, arabic

I want to open a text file (test.txt) that contains arabic text (its encoding is CP850), then print its content to STDOUT :

```
# coding : CP850
STDOUT.set_encoding(Encoding::CP850); # not sure if it's necessary
open('G:/test.txt',?r){|f|
    f.read.each_char{|c| print c};
    # or puts f.read;
}
gets
```

but it does not print the arabic characters, the output is some symbols and random characters.
Using Ruby 2.2.3

Comment: Can you please add some example name or an example on how the file looks like. Perhaps you can make it a sample available to download somewhere?

Comment: for example, this : http://pastebin.com/fhE8Yx0Y

Comment: I just tried your file in IRB. `string.split("\n").each { |line| puts line }` looks fine on my side. Things that might be different in my setup: I use default `UTF8` (instead of `CP850` like you do) and I have compiled Ruby with Readline support (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37480112/2483313).

Comment: [CP850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) doesn’t include Arabic characters, so the file can’t be in that encoding. You need to determine the _actual_ encoding of the file, and the encoding of your console (which may not be able to display Arabic).

Comment: @matt Thanks, I'll try compiling Ruby with Readline support and use the UTF-8 encoding instead of CP850

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding of the file to utf-8.

I don't know how this is accomplished in Ruby, but Django (the newer ones using Python 3), it's:

```
open('filename.txt', w, 'utf-8)
```

If you're using Python 2 it will be slightly more difficult. If so, it's worth upgrading to 3 just because it's native unicode and makes doing anything with Arabic a lot easier.