# Translating Names/Surnames from Arabic

Tags: ruby, translation, arabic

I'm working with Ruby, I have a list of names/surnames in the Arabic Language, I want to translate them to Latin, as they are pronounced, for example, I have the name `"رضوان" => "Redouane"` (I can also accept `Radouane`, `Radwan` or anything like this).

Public APIs like google translate work fine on some names, but when the name has a meaning, they fail to translate it "as it is pronounced", for example, with Google translate, to English, it gives : `"رمزي" => "symbolic"` while what I want is `"Ramzy"` (I can also accept `"Ramzi"`)

are there any good Ruby gems to translate names?

I'm trying to translate because I haven't been able to print arabic text to Ruby consoles directly, see : [Printing a CP850 encoded string with Ruby (IRB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447724/printing-a-cp850-encoded-string-with-ruby-irb)

Comment: I can accept mistakes, they aren't really a problem, what I want to do : I have a script that gathers some data from a server, the data contains a name and a surname in Arabic, and a grade, I want to display the name/surname in the console, I couldn't display Arabic on the console, so I tried translating.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic at all, and it should be reopened.

Comment: It won't let me add an answer, but just for the sake of posterity: what you're trying to do is not currently possible. There's just no way for an automated system to determine whether رمزي is being used as a proper or common noun.
So your best bet is to fix your output problem — I submitted an answer for you over there, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not a definite answer, but have you seen the [Unidecoder gem](https://github.com/norman/unidecoder)? It provides basic transliteration from any unicode letters to plain ASCII. However, it is indeed only a simple transliteration, e.g. it does not add vowels to the transcription. Quoting from the README:

> Other languages, like Hebrew and Arabic, don't write vowels, but assume them from context, so the ASCII representation of these langages given by this library will look fairly ugly to native speakers.

Your two examples yield to these transliterations:

```
require 'unidecoder'
=> true
>> "رضوان".to_ascii
=> "rDwn"
>> "رمزي".to_ascii
=> "rmzy"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it if I don't find better solutions.